# Getting the last day of the previous year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

How can I get the last date of the previous year e.g. 20211231 in SQL?

Or even to get the previous last dates in a list

```
20211231
20221231
20191231
20181231
```

I want to use that info in SSRS.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want the last day of the previous year? If you're going to use it at the end of a range for a report, `< {1st of this year}` is much more reliable to calculate then `<= {end of last year}`. I explain why in [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) and [this video](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9316/sql-server-between-dates-issue/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: This might also be useful: [Simplify date period calculations in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6088/simplify-date-period-calculations-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DATEFROMPARTS` would be one method:

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,12,31);
```

Another, on old completely unsupported versions, would be to use some date math:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0));
```

In future versions you could also use `DATE_BUCKET`:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATE_BUCKET(YEAR,1,GETDATE()));
--or use a different origin
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(YEAR,1,GETDATE(),CONVERT(datetime,'19001231'));
```

Honestly, `DATEFROMPARTS` is probably the "cleanest" and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```